# Ransack not to filter issue

Tags: activeadmin, ransack

I have a filter in ActiveAdmin resource page:

```
  filter :active_in, label: 'Active', as: :select, collection: ['All', 'Yes', 'No']
```

and ransacker for it:

```
  ransacker :active, formatter: proc {|value|
    results = Model.active.ids if value == 'Yes'
    results = Model.inactive.ids if value == 'No'
    results.present? ? results : nil

  } do |parent|
    parent.table[:id]
  end
```

The issue is if i select 'All' it should display all the data without filtering, instead if this it tries to filter Model's by id with 'null'.

```
SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM `models` WHERE `models`.`id` IN (NULL) LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
```

For 'Yes' and 'No' it works correctly.